# Quivec3 scales vectors in different directions unequally

Tags: matlab

I have used quiver3 to plot a 3d vector field which is on a 2d plane but vectors can point to the third direction. My problem s that the plot shows these vectors with an unreasonable scale. As an example look at the different components of the specified vector in the following figure. Although the vector has the same value along x and y and z, the plot shows it so that it seems the vector is along z.

[image]

Could someone please help me with solving this issue? I used the following to make this plot:

```
uX = [1,3,1;2,2,1;1,1,1];
uY = [0.5,1,1;1,1.5,1;1,1,1];
uZ = [2,3,1;0,0.5,0;1,1,0.5];

[ x, y ] = meshgrid(1:3, 1:3); %x is 199 by 199, y too
zcomp = zeros(3,3);
scale=1;
quiver3(x(1:3,1:3),y(1:3,1:3),zcomp(1:3,1:3),uX(1:3,1:3),uY(1:3,1:3),uZ(1:3,1:3),scale)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the data aspect ratio in your plot.
Either do

```
axis equal
```

or use [`daspect`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/daspect.html)

```
daspect([1 1 1])
```

to set the aspect ratio between the different axis.

[image]